# FTP Directory name with spaces not accessible in iOS programmatically

Tags: ios, ftp, cfstream

I have to access the folder name with spaces, but I am getting 550 error which means file does not exist.

ftp://192.xxx.xx.x/C/xxx/xxxx/**xxx xxx xxx**/5mb.jpg

I can access directories upto this path 
ftp://192.xxx.xx.x/C/xxx/xxxx/

But after that, as there is space in directory name (in bold), it is not accessible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace the spaces with below and try again

```
%20
```

Comment: can you access the image through browser ?

Comment: Not under that particular directory

Comment: Anyway got it working, removed all other encodings done and just used %20 Thanks